# How do i initialize array of a another class?

Tags: java

I am trying to initialize an array based on user input so it can be of any custom size. By default i have initialized array to 10 with all 0.0 values but when I try call the method that initializes the array nothing happens and the values neither the size or the values in the array change.

Class Numbers:

```
public class Numbers {
private Float [] numbers;
private int default_size = 10;

public Numbers() {
    ///  write code here to intialize a "default" array since this is the default constructor
    numbers = new Float[default_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < default_size; i++)
    numbers [i] = (float) 0.0;
}

public Numbers (int size) {
    ///  write code here to initialize an "initial" array given the parameter size as this is an initial constructor
    numbers = new Float[size];
}

public void initValuesInArray() {
    /// write code here to intialize the values in the array
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Value : ");
        numbers[i] = scan.nextFloat();
    }
}

public String toString() {
    // write code to return the values in the array in a list format - one value per line
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    return " ";
}

public float calcAverage() {
    // write code to return the average of the values in the array
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        sum += numbers[i];
    double average = sum / numbers.length;
    System.out.println(average);
    return (float) average;
}
```

}

Class Main:

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String [] args) {

    // write the code here to implement the menu as specified in Lab 1

    boolean menuLoop = true;
    while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to initialize a default array");
    System.out.println("Enter 2 to initialize an array of input size");
    System.out.println("Enter 3 fill array with values");
    System.out.println("Enter 4 display values in array");
    System.out.println("Enter 5 to display average of the values in the array");
    System.out.println("6 to quit\n");

    Numbers obj = new Numbers();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();

    switch (i) {

    case 1:
        obj = new Numbers ();
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter the new size of array: ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        Numbers [] numbers = new Numbers[x];
        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("Enter the float numbers as values in the array: ");
        obj.initValuesInArray();
        break;

    case 4:
        obj.toString();
        break;

    case 5:
        obj.calcAverage();
        break;

    case 6:
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    default :
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry...");
        break;
        }

    } 
}
```

}

It needs to be able to change the size of the array based on user input and thereafter the user can enter the values into the array.

EDIT:

I think i have finally figured out the issue here and that is when i use break in the switch statement it initializes the array to default which is 10 with all 0.0 values. Although i am not sure how to make the array hold the input value if the option selected is 2

Comment: You're doing `Numbers[] numbers = new Numbers[x]` instead of `obj = new Numbers[x]`.

Comment: i already tried that but when i do that it gives me a type mismatch error

Comment: Why do you not whant to use an ArrayList to avoid the problem of an array size?

Comment: Instead of implementing two different constructors at Numbers, I'd recommend giving size a default value and checking in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `public Numbers (int size)` constructor you've made in the `Numbers` class. Also you're creating a new variable called `numbers`, rather than assigning the local field `obj`. This:

```
    Numbers [] numbers = new Numbers[x];
```

should be

```
    obj = new Numbers(x);
```

Comment: tried it still it doesn't make any difference to the array size. The values or the size of the array doesn't change

Comment: @JustinMacwan I read through your post again and edited my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't change the size of the array and it stays 10 with 0.0 values

Comment: @JustinMacwan can you let me know how you know that? Please share the code where you're reading the length of the array after setting its size in `case 2`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Array if your amount of elements is not fixed. Instead, use `List` or `ArrayList` (subclass of List).

You can find all the methods you need at:
[developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList)

*EDIT 24/01/19*:

If you need the `List` or `ArrayList` to be 10 by default just in case the user doesn't input a value, you can create an `IF/ELSE` which fills the List automatically or maybe use the `SWITCH CASE` you already have

For example:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
float defaultValue = 0.0;

case 1:
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myList.add(defaultValue)
    }
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("Enter the new size of array: ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        myList.add(defaultValue)
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Use `List` or `ArrayList` does not really make sense. You mean use a `LinkedList` or an `ArrayList` maybe?

Comment: I need to have it default to 10 if the user doesn't want to input an array size so by default it has to be set to 10

Comment: I added a solution for that just now. Hope it works.

Comment: This code won't work because you can not use a primitive as a type. `ArrayList<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();` Also, you should code towards interfaces when possible, so it should be: `List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: This could technically work but I can’t use ArrayList in this solution unfortunately

Comment: Why not? What problems did you come up with? I will do my best to solve those issues.

Comment: Because this is part or my lab solution and we are only supposed to use Arrays in the solution